# How do you write a VSCode run configuration that will run the current Python file as a module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VSCode automatically generates something like this:

```
        {
            "name": "Foobar",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "project.folder.foobar",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
```

I would like to have a configuration which always works for the current file so that I have to switch less.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this a good general solution but it seems to work for now:

```
        {
            "name": "Current Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "project.${fileDirnameBasename}.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
```

Note: This doesn't work for folders with different nesting levels. I haven't been able to find a way to automatically transform `foo/bar/baz` into `foo.bar.baz` yet.

Comment: Hi Sarien, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Please note that this will only work if the Python file you're trying to run is in your `PYTHONPATH` or in the same directory as the file you're running.